# what is the most straightforward way to substitute characters at nonadjacent indices in a string with a given value in R?

Tags: r, string

I have a string "pavel", I would like to substitute values 2 and 4 with "X" to get "pXvXl". Can I do it with one line of code, specifying positions as a vector c(2, 4)? As far as I understand substring only works for adjacent positions.

Comment: Perhaps a one-liner `for` loop: `for (i in c(2, 4)) substr(x, i, i+1) <- "X"` where `x <- "pavel"`.